# Image foregroundColor bugs when view gets updated

Tags: swift, image, button, swiftui

My view contains like-buttons, but when the view gets updated, the like-buttons get reloaded, and for a split second, the like-buttons that are liked ("heart.fill") show the neutral image for one second ("heart").
This happens when I click on other buttons that update the view.
I can't figure out why this problem occurs.

```
struct CommentCell: View {
    @ObservedObject private var commentRowViewModel: CommentRowViewModel
    
    init(post: Post, comment: Comment) {
        commentRowViewModel = CommentRowViewModel(comment: comment, post: post)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
      VStack {
                    Button {
                        commentRowViewModel.comment.didLike ?? false ?
                        commentRowViewModel.unlikeComment() :
                        commentRowViewModel.likeComment()
                    } label: {
                        let didLike = commentRowViewModel.comment.didLike ?? false
                        
                        ZStack {
                            Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                                .opacity(didLike ? 1 : 0)
                                .foregroundColor(Color(r: 221, g: 102, b: 91))
                            Image(systemName: "heart")
                                .opacity(didLike ? 0 : 1)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        }
                    }
                    Text("\(commentRowViewModel.comment.likes)")
                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                }
    }
    
 class CommentRowViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var comment: Comment
    let service = CommentService()
    let post: Post
    
    init(comment: Comment, post: Post) {
        self.comment = comment
        self.post = post
        checkIfUserLikedComment()
    }
    
    func likeComment() {
        service.likeComment(post: post, comment: comment) { likes in
            self.comment.didLike = true
            self.comment.likes = likes
        }
    }
    
    func checkIfUserLikedComment() {
        service.checkIfUserLikedComment(comment: comment) { didLike in
            if didLike {
                self.comment.didLike = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    func unlikeComment() {
        service.unlikeComment(post: post, comment: comment) {likes in
            self.comment.didLike = false
            self.comment.likes = likes
        }
    }
}

struct CommentService {
   
    func likeComment(post: Post, comment: Comment, completion: @escaping(Int) -> Void) {
        let newValue = comment.likes + 1
        
        guard let uid = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid else {return}
        guard let postId = post.id else {return}
        guard let commentId = comment.id else {return}
        
        let userLikesRef = FirebaseManager.shared.firestore.collection("users").document(uid).collection("comment-likes")
        
        FirebaseManager.shared.firestore.collection("posts").document(postId).collection("comments").document(commentId)
            .updateData(["likes": newValue]) { error in
                if error != nil {
                    print("Failed with finding userLikes")
                    return
                }
                
                userLikesRef.document(commentId).setData([:]) { err in
                    if err != nil {
                        print("Failed with err", err ?? "")
                        return
                    }
                    
                    completion(newValue)
                }
            }
    }
    
    func unlikeComment(post: Post, comment: Comment, completion: @escaping(Int) -> Void) {
        
        guard let uid = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid else {return}
        guard let postId = post.id else {return}
        guard let commentId = comment.id else {return}
        guard comment.likes > 0 else {return}
        let newValue = comment.likes - 1
        
        let userLikesRef = FirebaseManager.shared.firestore.collection("users").document(uid).collection("comment-likes")
        
        FirebaseManager.shared.firestore.collection("posts").document(postId).collection("comments").document(commentId)
            .updateData(["likes": newValue]) { error in
                
                if error != nil {
                    print("failed to unlike", error ?? "")
                    return
                }
                
                userLikesRef.document(commentId).delete { err in
                    if err != nil {
                        print(err ?? "")
                        return
                    }
                    
                    completion(newValue)
                }
            }
    }
    
    func checkIfUserLikedComment(comment: Comment, completion: @escaping(Bool)->Void) {
        guard let uid = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid else {return}
        guard let commentId = comment.id else {return}
        
        FirebaseManager.shared.firestore.collection("users")
            .document(uid)
            .collection("comment-likes")
            .document(commentId)
            .getDocument { snapshot, error in
                if error != nil {
                    print("Failed to fetch if user have liked post", error ?? "")
                    return
                }
                guard let snap = snapshot else {return}
                
                completion(snap.exists)
            }
            
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You really need to go back and produce an MRE. You may find your own solution in so doing.

Comment: You create service and view model inside each row, so once row re-created (which might happen often) you recreate/refetch everything... I assume that should live outside of UI and just be injected in row for usage.

Comment: Probably unrelated but never (z)stack multiple views conditionally which are supposed to represent different states of the same view. Use one view and set the appearance conditionally like you set the `opacity` and  get rid of the ZStack.